# Test list of URLs with linter/debugger

Tags: facebook, debugging

Is there a way to test an entire list of URLs with the Facebook url linter / debugger rather than testing them one at a time?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the source of the debugger then you'll see that it's a simple html form, you can probably just do the same, create a page that takes a few urls and submits each one to the same action the debugger uses.

There's a chance that the server side of the debugger checks where the request originated from (some kind of csrf maybe?) but I doubt that.

The only question is why would you want to do such a thing?